# ZFS messed mirrors up

Tags: raid, zfs

I have a ZFS pool with 6 drives in RAID10 -- well, it used to.

I tried to upgrade a 146GB drive to 1TB drive, and messed up bad.

```
root@x7550:~# zpool status
  pool: stuffpool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0 in 0h6m with 0 errors on Mon May  9 15:26:39 2016
config:

    NAME                                               STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    stuffpool                                          ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0                                         ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-HGST_HTS721010A9E630_JR10004M0LGN6E-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-HGST_HTS721010A9E630_JR10004M0M17TE-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-1                                         ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-HGST_HTS541010A9E680_JA1000102MG9UR-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-HGST_HTS541010A9E680_JA1009C03158BP-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
      scsi-35000c50016ebcdfb-part1                     ONLINE       0     0     0
      ata-HGST_HTS541010A9E680_JA109NDW206MAS-part1    ONLINE       0     0     0
```

`scsi-35000c50016ebcdfb-part1` use to be in mirror-2 and `ata-HGST_HTS541010A9E680_JA109NDW206MAS-part1` is the drive I was trying to add to mirror-2.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

I am running on ubuntu 16.04

```
root@x7550:~# zpool history stuffpool | tail -n50
History for 'stuffpool':
2016-03-27.01:56:12 zpool create stuffpool mirror ata-HGST_HTS721010A9E630_JR10004M0LGN6E-part1 ata-HGST_HTS721010A9E630_JR10004M0M17TE-part1 -f
2016-03-27.01:57:41 zpool add stuffpool mirror /dev/disk/by-id/ata-HGST_HTS541010A9E680_JA1000102MG9UR-part1 /dev/disk/by-id/ata-HGST_HTS541010A9E680_JA1009C03158BP-part1 -f
2016-03-27.01:59:25 zpool add stuffpool mirror /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c50016ebcdfb-part1 /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c50017675203-part1 -f
2016-03-27.02:12:38 zpool import -c /etc/zfs/zpool.cache -aN
2016-03-27.23:48:32 zfs create stuffpool/stuff
2016-03-27.23:54:47 zpool import -c /etc/zfs/zpool.cache -aN
2016-03-28.00:02:23 zfs create stuffpool/backup
2016-03-30.23:18:04 zpool scrub stuffpool
2016-04-03.01:06:06 zpool import -c /etc/zfs/zpool.cache -aN
2016-04-03.01:15:33 zfs create -p -o mountpoint=/var/lib/lxd/images/f96b6b5d7587150b880e96f872393b7fee53741046b40a76c6db22ed40886bc9.zfs stuffpool/images/f96b6b5d7587150b880e96f872393b7fee53741046b40a76c6db22ed40886bc9
2016-04-03.01:15:53 zfs set readonly=on stuffpool/images/f96b6b5d7587150b880e96f872393b7fee53741046b40a76c6db22ed40886bc9
2016-04-03.01:15:54 zfs snapshot -r stuffpool/images/f96b6b5d7587150b880e96f872393b7fee53741046b40a76c6db22ed40886bc9@readonly
2016-04-03.01:16:00 zfs clone -p -o mountpoint=/var/lib/lxd/containers/ux-1.zfs stuffpool/images/f96b6b5d7587150b880e96f872393b7fee53741046b40a76c6db22ed40886bc9@readonly stuffpool/containers/ux-1
2016-04-08.01:31:47 zpool import -c /etc/zfs/zpool.cache -aN
2016-04-08.01:43:48 zpool import -c /etc/zfs/zpool.cache -aN
2016-04-19.00:00:30 zpool import -c /etc/zfs/zpool.cache -aN
2016-04-21.18:14:15 zfs create -p -o mountpoint=/var/lib/lxd/images/9b03bacc30bcfbe3378e8803daa48ca2d32baa99d111efada484876750e5cc20.zfs stuffpool/images/9b03bacc30bcfbe3378e8803daa48ca2d32baa99d111efada484876750e5cc20
2016-04-21.18:14:35 zfs set readonly=on stuffpool/images/9b03bacc30bcfbe3378e8803daa48ca2d32baa99d111efada484876750e5cc20
2016-04-21.18:14:36 zfs snapshot -r stuffpool/images/9b03bacc30bcfbe3378e8803daa48ca2d32baa99d111efada484876750e5cc20@readonly
2016-04-21.18:14:36 zfs set mountpoint=none stuffpool/images/f96b6b5d7587150b880e96f872393b7fee53741046b40a76c6db22ed40886bc9
2016-04-21.18:14:41 zfs rename -p stuffpool/images/f96b6b5d7587150b880e96f872393b7fee53741046b40a76c6db22ed40886bc9 stuffpool/deleted/images/f96b6b5d7587150b880e96f872393b7fee53741046b40a76c6db22ed40886bc9
2016-04-24.22:54:03 zpool scrub stuffpool
2016-05-07.22:55:42 zpool import -c /etc/zfs/zpool.cache -aN
2016-05-09.15:20:27 zpool scrub stuffpool
2016-05-17.22:56:53 zfs create -p -o mountpoint=/var/lib/lxd/images/4f7a1fe6b71446eba6ee56f49698bd6592f193f731f1c0d9d51b1d199b9b75a5.zfs stuffpool/images/4f7a1fe6b71446eba6ee56f49698bd6592f193f731f1c0d9d51b1d199b9b75a5
2016-05-17.22:57:12 zfs set readonly=on stuffpool/images/4f7a1fe6b71446eba6ee56f49698bd6592f193f731f1c0d9d51b1d199b9b75a5
2016-05-17.22:57:13 zfs snapshot -r stuffpool/images/4f7a1fe6b71446eba6ee56f49698bd6592f193f731f1c0d9d51b1d199b9b75a5@readonly
2016-05-17.22:57:18 zfs destroy -r stuffpool/images/9b03bacc30bcfbe3378e8803daa48ca2d32baa99d111efada484876750e5cc20
2016-05-21.16:47:49 zpool import -c /etc/zfs/zpool.cache -aN
2016-06-09.22:59:47 zpool import -c /etc/zfs/zpool.cache -aN
2016-06-13.20:59:10 zpool import -c /etc/zfs/zpool.cache -aN
2016-06-13.20:59:34 zfs create -p -o mountpoint=/var/lib/lxd/images/49fc7d0d6f01a7639129308b73ad27f5fb7b9d3bb783d905393b6b9e9c4bf1c5.zfs stuffpool/images/49fc7d0d6f01a7639129308b73ad27f5fb7b9d3bb783d905393b6b9e9c4bf1c5
2016-06-13.20:59:54 zfs set readonly=on stuffpool/images/49fc7d0d6f01a7639129308b73ad27f5fb7b9d3bb783d905393b6b9e9c4bf1c5
2016-06-13.20:59:54 zfs snapshot -r stuffpool/images/49fc7d0d6f01a7639129308b73ad27f5fb7b9d3bb783d905393b6b9e9c4bf1c5@readonly
2016-06-13.21:00:00 zfs destroy -r stuffpool/images/4f7a1fe6b71446eba6ee56f49698bd6592f193f731f1c0d9d51b1d199b9b75a5
2016-06-18.02:18:55 zpool import -c /etc/zfs/zpool.cache -aN
2016-06-18.02:27:08 zpool offline stuffpool 1759097636360003165
2016-06-18.02:33:28 zpool detach stuffpool 1759097636360003165
2016-06-18.12:23:26 zpool export stuffpool
2016-06-18.12:24:38 zpool import stuffpool
2016-06-18.12:27:34 zpool add -f stuffpool ata-HGST_HTS541010A9E680_JA109NDW206MAS-part1
2016-06-18.12:31:05 zpool export stuffpool
2016-06-18.13:19:17 zpool import stuffpool
```

All the ATA drives are 1tb and the SCSI drivers are 146GB

Here is the usage info

```
root@x7550:~# zpool list
NAME        SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
stuffpool  2.85T   162G  2.69T         -     2%     5%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
```

This is my personal server, so downtime isn't an issue.

Comment: Show us `zpool history stuffpool | tail -n50` or so. My *guess* would be that you did a `detach` of the drive you removed and an `add` (instead of `attach`) of the new drive, in which case you have a problem (but one that I think just might be possible to solve in place with minimal disruption of service). The pool history will tell us exactly what you did to the pool, which will help inform us on how the problem can be fixed. Just whatever you do, don't rush things now. (The *correct* thing to do to begin with -- not now! -- would have been to `replace` the old drive with the new drive.)

Comment: It would also be good if you can tell us the sizes of each respective drive, and how much data total is in the pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, you only have 160GB of data on your pool.

If you have a directory on another filesystem with enough free space to store ~160GB of backup data, or less with compression, (I'll use  `/var/backup/` in my example), you can:

First, kill any processes that might be writing anything to `stuffpool`.  Kill `crond` and `atd` etc too, if there are any cron etc jobs that might write to `stuffpool`.

Create a full backup of `stuffpool` with `zfs send -R`, saving it to a file:

```
zfs snapshot stuffpool@fullbackup
zfs send -R stuffpool@fullbackup | gzip > /var/backup/stuffpool.zfs.send.gz
```

BTW, compressing the backup not only takes less disk space, it should take less time to backup and restore....any CPU time used by `gzip` will almost always be far less than the time saved by reading/writing significantly less data to/from disk.  Disk I/O is the bottleneck, and generally takes more time than compression.

Next, destroy the current pool with `zfs destroy stuffpool`.

Re-create stuffpool with:

```
zpool create -o ashift=12 -o checksum=sha256 -f \
  mirror \
    ata-HGST_HTS721010A9E630_JR10004M0M17TE-part1 \
    ata-HGST_HTS541010A9E680_JA1009C03158BP-part1 \
  mirror \
    ata-HGST_HTS721010A9E630_JR10004M0LGN6E-part1 \
    ata-HGST_HTS541010A9E680_JA1000102MG9UR-part1 \
  mirror \
    scsi-35000c50016ebcdfb-part1 \
    ata-HGST_HTS541010A9E680_JA109NDW206MAS-part1
```

Finally, restore `stuffpool` with:

```
zcat /var/backup/stuffpool.zfs.send.gz | zfs receive stuffpool -v -d
```

If you want, you can tidy up the pool by deleting the `fullbackup` snapshot:

```
zfs destroy stuffpool@fullbackup
```

or you can leave it there as a point-in-time snapshot of when you had to rebuild your pool.

The `/var/backup/stuffpool.zfs.send.gz` can be deleted.

---

If you don't have enough spare disk space on an existing filesystem, you can detach one of the mirror disks from the existing stuffpool, format it and use it to temporarily store the `stuffpool.zfs.send.gz` file.

Using `ata-HGST_HTS721010A9E630_JR10004M0LGN6E-part1` as an example:

```
zpool detach stuffpool ata-HGST_HTS721010A9E630_JR10004M0LGN6E-part1

mkfs.ext4 /dev/disk/by-id/ata-HGST_HTS721010A9E630_JR10004M0LGN6E-part1
mount /dev/disk/by-id/ata-HGST_HTS721010A9E630_JR10004M0LGN6E-part1 /mnt

zfs snapshot stuffpool@fullbackup
zfs send -R stuffpool@fullbackup | gzip > /mnt/stuffpool.zfs.send.gz

zfs destroy stuffpool

zpool create -o ashift=12 -o checksum=sha256 -f \
    ata-HGST_HTS541010A9E680_JA1009C03158BP-part1 \
  mirror \
    ata-HGST_HTS721010A9E630_JR10004M0LGN6E-part1 \
    ata-HGST_HTS541010A9E680_JA1000102MG9UR-part1 \
  mirror \
    scsi-35000c50016ebcdfb-part1 \
    ata-HGST_HTS541010A9E680_JA109NDW206MAS-part1

zcat /mnt/stuffpool.zfs.send.gz | zfs receive stuffpool -v -d

umount /mnt

zpool attach -f stuffpool \
    ata-HGST_HTS541010A9E680_JA1009C03158BP-part1 \
    ata-HGST_HTS721010A9E630_JR10004M0LGN6E-part1
```

Answer (score 6):

Okay, you have made a bit of a mess for yourself, but it looks like it's fixable.

The first mistake you made was to `zpool add` the new drive, instead of `zpool attach` (attach an additional device to a mirror) or even better `zpool replace` with the old device still present in the pool metadata. The correct way to replace the device would have been to

```
# zpool replace stuffpool 1759097636360003165 ata-HGST_HTS541010A9E680_JA109NDW206MAS-part1
```

or even better, if you had the physical ability, `zpool replace` the old device with the new device with both connected (that would have maintained pool redundancy throughout the process).

**Your old pool is basically broken beyond repair** at this point: you can't remove a vdev from a pool after it's been added (mismatching vdev redundancy levels is likely why you needed `-f` to get the new disk into the pool), and you don't have the hardware to turn the two non-redundant vdevs into two-way mirrors.

You can, however, **make a new pool out of what you do have.**

**Read through all of this before you take any action, and make sure you understand the what and the why of each step. You *really* don't want to mess up further.**

First, make absolutely sure that you have an up-to-date, *reliable* backup of your data. Given that you have only a bit over 160 GB stored, that shouldn't be much of a problem. I also very strongly recommend a `zpool scrub` to make sure that all stored data on the pool is free of any errors. With 160 GB, and also as indicated by your previous scrub, it shouldn't take long to complete.

Then, free one drive by detaching it from a mirror. For example, to break mirror-0 apart and use one of the drives there, you might

```
# zpool detach stuffpool ata-HGST_HTS721010A9E630_JR10004M0M17TE-part1
```

This will leave you with `stuffpool` made up of three single-device vdevs and one two-way mirror vdev (mirror-1). Then clear all ZFS labels on the drive that you broke away from the mirror, so that you can repurpose it:

```
# zpool labelclear /dev/disk/by-id/ata-HGST_HTS721010A9E630_JR10004M0M17TE-part1
```

At this point, ZFS will not recognize the drive as part of your old pool. You might need `-f` to `zpool labelclear`, but do not add it blindly; make sure you understand why you might need it.

Rename the old pool (assuming you want to retain the name, otherwise adjust below as needed):

```
# zpool export stuffpool
# zpool import stuffpool stuffpoolold
```

Create a new pool on the freed up drive:

```
# zpool create -o ashift=12 -O checksum=sha256 -m none -f stuffpool /dev/disk/by-id/ata-HGST_HTS721010A9E630_JR10004M0M17TE-part1
```

I recommend using SHA-256 for checksums, but if you don't want to, you can omit the `-O checksum=sha256` part. `-o ashift=12` tells ZFS to use 4,096 byte blocks as the minimum allocation unit, which works better with "Advanced Format" drives at a small storage space cost.

Some failure conditions are easier to recover from if you don't use the root file system on the pool for storing data. I suggest that you create a surrogate root file system on the pool:

```
# zfs create -o mountpoint=/mnt/stuffpoolnew stuffpool/data
```

Now, transfer everything from the old pool to the new pool. First create a snapshot of the current state of the old pool:

```
# zfs snapshot stuffpoolold@transfer -r
```

Make sure the snapshot is created successfully. Then:

```
# zfs send -R stuffpoolold@transfer | zfs receive -uvF stuffpool/data
```

This will take a while. Let it run to completion, then grab anything that changed in the meantime:

```
# zfs snapshot stuffpoolold@transfer2 -r
# zfs send -I stuffpoolold@transfer stuffpoolold@transfer2 -Rv | zfs receive stuffpool/data -uv
```

At this point, the data on the pools should for all intents and purposes be identical. If you have cron jobs or similar things running that write to the pool, consider making the second snapshot and the `zfs send -I ...` from single-user mode to reduce the risk of data being added to the pool.

Set up the new pool to take the place of the old pool:

```
# zfs get mountpoint stuffpoolold
... this will give you a mountpoint directory ...
# zpool export stuffpoolold
# zfs set mountpoint=...mountpoint_directory_from_above... stuffpool/data
# zpool export stuffpool
# zpool import stuffpool
```

At this point, you have the new zpool consisting of just a single device. Scrub it to make sure the data is fine:

```
# zpool scrub stuffpool
```

When it finishes without finding any errors, proceed with migrating the old disks to the new pool. Start with the second drive of the old remaining mirror-1 pair (because we used the second drive of mirror-0 above), to maintain the old pool as importable for as long as possible:

```
# zpool labelclear /dev/disk/by-id/ata-HGST_HTS541010A9E680_JA1009C03158BP-part1
# zpool attach stuffpool /dev/disk/by-id/ata-HGST_HTS721010A9E630_JR10004M0M17TE-part1 /dev/disk/by-id/ata-HGST_HTS541010A9E680_JA1009C03158BP-part1
```

Check `zpool status stuffpool` to ensure that you now have a pool consisting of a single two-way mirror vdev, something like this:

```
root@x7550:~# zpool status stuffpool
  pool: stuffpool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0 in 0h6m with 0 errors on ...
config:

    NAME                                               STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    stuffpool                                          ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0                                         ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-HGST_HTS721010A9E630_JR10004M0M17TE-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-HGST_HTS541010A9E680_JA1009C03158BP-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

Now go ahead and add two more mirror vdevs the way you wanted them in the first place. You will need to labelclear the devices first (otherwise ZFS will complain that they are already part of an exported pool). Again, you might need `-f` to `zpool labelclear`, but *absolutely do not* blindly add `-f` to `zpool add`. (If you have to, then I've made a mistake somewhere.)

```
# zpool labelclear /dev/disk/by-id/ata-HGST_HTS721010A9E630_JR10004M0LGN6E-part1
# zpool labelclear /dev/disk/by-id/ata-HGST_HTS541010A9E680_JA1000102MG9UR-part1
# zpool labelclear /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c50016ebcdfb-part1
# zpool labelclear /dev/disk/by-id/ata-HGST_HTS541010A9E680_JA109NDW206MAS-part1
# zpool add stuffpool mirror /dev/disk/by-id/ata-HGST_HTS721010A9E630_JR10004M0LGN6E-part1 /dev/disk/by-id/ata-HGST_HTS541010A9E680_JA1000102MG9UR-part1
# zpool add stuffpool mirror /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c50016ebcdfb-part1 /dev/disk/by-id/ata-HGST_HTS541010A9E680_JA109NDW206MAS-part1
```

Scrub again (because everybody loves their pools nice and clean):

```
# zpool scrub stuffpool
```

At this point, your pool should look like you wanted it from the beginning:

```
root@x7550:~# zpool status
  pool: stuffpool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0 in 0h6m with 0 errors on ...
config:

    NAME                                               STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    stuffpool                                          ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0                                         ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-HGST_HTS721010A9E630_JR10004M0M17TE-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-HGST_HTS541010A9E680_JA1009C03158BP-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-1                                         ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-HGST_HTS721010A9E630_JR10004M0LGN6E-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-HGST_HTS541010A9E680_JA1000102MG9UR-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-2                                         ONLINE       0     0     0
        scsi-35000c50016ebcdfb-part1                   ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-HGST_HTS541010A9E680_JA109NDW206MAS-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

Your pool is now unbalanced (almost all of the data is on mirror-0, and will remain there until rewritten; though ZFS lacks anything resembling `btrfs rebalance`, you can still fix that with judicious use of `zfs send ... | zfs receive`), but it has the layout and redundancy that you intended when you started out.

**It's a long process with lots of steps, but if you take it nice and slow, and think carefully about what you are doing at each step, it isn't particularly dangerous.**

**The saving grace was that you had significantly less data on the pool than what would fill even any one drive. If your pool had been nearly full, this would have been much more complex.**

Comment: +1 and two comments.  1. if OP has spare drives, ports, and drive bays he can attach a disk to each of  `scsi-35000c50016ebcdfb-part1` and `ata-HGST_HTS541010A9E680_JA109NDW206MAS-part1`, turning them into `mirror-2` and `mirror-3`.   2. given that it's only 160GB and OP has (or **should have**) a full, recent backup before doing anything else, the best option is to just destroy the pool and re-create it from scratch, then restore the data...that would avoid the pool being unbalanced.

Comment: Also worth mentioning: a full backup with all snapshots etc intact can be made with something like: `zfs snapshot stuffpool@fullbackup ; zfs send -R stuffpool@fullbackup > /path/to/dir/with/enough/space/backupfile`.  and restore with `zfs receive` later.  The `@fullbackup` snapshot can be destroyed from the pool after the restore.